# gunicorn.service: Failed to determine user credentials: No such process - django, gunicorn, and nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

When I run `sudo systemctl status gunicorn`, I get the following error:

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-02-08 07:29:18 UTC; 17min ago
 Main PID: 21841 (code=exited, status=217/USER)

Feb 08 07:29:18 ip-172-31-37-113 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Feb 08 07:29:18 ip-172-31-37-113 systemd[21841]: gunicorn.service: Failed to determine user credentials: No such process
Feb 08 07:29:18 ip-172-31-37-113 systemd[21841]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step USER spawning /home/ubuntu/bookclub/venv/bin/gun
Feb 08 07:29:18 ip-172-31-37-113 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
Feb 08 07:29:18 ip-172-31-37-113 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) from DigitalOcean to get my Django website onto my EC2 instance. I'm using Nginx and Gunicorn with Django to accomplish this.

This is my `gunicorn.service` file at `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sammy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/bookclub
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/bookclub/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/bookclub/books.sock books.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I checked for `books.sock` in my project folder with `ls` and I saw that `books.sock` *does not exist*.

## Edit

I changed `User` in my Gunicorn service file from `sammy` (which didn't exist) to `ubuntu` (which is the only one that exists on the server).

So my `gunicorn.service` looks like this now:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sammy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/bookclub
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/bookclub/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/bookclub/books.sock books.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But I get another error:

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-02-08 09:23:41 UTC; 19s ago
 Main PID: 22533 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Feb 08 09:23:41 ip-172-31-37-113 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Feb 08 09:23:41 ip-172-31-37-113 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Feb 08 09:23:41 ip-172-31-37-113 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Are you sure user `sammy` exists on that system? Try to put `User=ubuntu` (afair it's default user on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks, @SUTerliakov! That removed the error `failed to determine user credentials`, but `systemctl status gunicorn` shows that `gunicorn` has failed. I will edit my question to include this.

Comment: Now try to `sudo chown ubuntu /home/ubuntu/bookclub/venv/bin/gunicorn` and see if it helps. If not - post also output of `journalctl --since="-1h"`

Comment: There is nothing at `sudo chown ubuntu /home/ubuntu/bookclub/venv/bin/gunicorn`. I wonder if that's the issue? Gunicorn can't access that but it is in ExecStart? 
Here's the error:
`chown: cannot access '/home/ubuntu/bookclub/venv/bin/gunicorn': No such file or directory`

Comment: Yep, it's definitely a problem... Your `ExecStart` points to non-existing file. You have to `pip install gunicorn` into that venv first.

Comment: But I have it installed... should I reinstall it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241815/discussion-between-robo-and-suterliakov).

Answer (score 1):

You were misleaded because there in an external procedure to follow at the beginning of the session: [initial server setup guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-16-04).

To do:

> Create user sammy

Important

```
usermod -aG sudo sammy
```

Switch to sammy profile

Create django project under sammy profile

```
pwd
/home/sammy
```

Everything will work fine

The reason ? 1_maybe this is the DB user 2_Maybe root profile is not valid.
God knows.
Good luck.